# Motion of light in a Medium with Refractive Index varying Radially

Tags: optics, photons, conservation-laws

I recently came across a question, where we were asked to determine the minimum distance a light ray would come to the origin of a coordinate system when the refractive index was directly proportional to the radial distance of the ray. I tried to solve the problem using Snell's Law which states that $$n(r)\sin{\theta} = const$$$\theta$ is the angle between the ray and the normal. The constant can be determined from the initial conditions specified. However, this gave me the wrong answer. 
I decided to adopt a different method which used some pretty far-fetched ideas, yet gave the right result. I have described it below.
I drew an analogy to a similar problem in celestial mechanics, where we can find the minimum distance of a celestial body from another fixed body by using Conservation of Angular Momentum (COAM), along with Energy Conservation. I imagined my light ray to consist of particles (can be considered to be photons) moving in a medium where its velocity varies radially. This variation can be found using the definition of refractive index, i.e $$v(r) = \frac{c}{n(r)}$$ Applying COAM to this photon,
$$mvr\sin{\theta} = const$$ where m is the 'mass of the photon' which can be written as $m = \frac{hf}{v^2}$. When we put everything together, using the given data, we arrive at the conclusion that $r^2\sin{\theta} = const$ using which we can find the minimum distance. 
Although this works, I have made some questionable (and possibly wrong) assumptions.

1. Why doesn't the first method seem to work?
2. Is it valid to apply COAM to a photon?
3. Is the mass of a photon even defined? If it is, then is it correct to assume that the mass the photon will vary radially with distance? (Considering the way I have used it)
4. Is the second method a 'hack' or is there some intuition behind why it holds?

Thanks.

Comment: "...and the normal" normal to what?

Comment: Normal to a spherical boundary separating two layers of the medium

Comment: whats the min dist for radial rays?

Comment: The rays are not radial, the rays form an arbitrary angle with the normal that is not 0°

Comment: i meant does the correct formula predict $0$ at normal incidence

Comment: When you used the method I described above, the minimum comes out to be $R\sqrt{\sin{\theta}}$ where R is the initial distance from the origin and $\theta$ is the initial angle made by the ray with the normal. To find this minimum, I used the fact that at minimum distance, the ray must be perpendicular to the normal